# In the sentence showed by this question is the word "though" necessary or at least useful?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjugations

I have found the following sentence:

> Do you know of any benchmarks, though, that demonstrate the speedup granted by bytecode compilation?

I can't understand the sense of the word `though` in the sentence. On my opinion the sentence is more clear without it:

> Do you know of any benchmarks that demonstrate the speedup granted by bytecode compilation?

#### My question

In the previous sentence, does the word `though` change the meaning or add only a bit of confusion?

Comment: The word 'though' refers back to something that was said previously. Probably about compilation or code execution speed. Person A: I don't know of any meat that tastes good with potatoes! Person B: Do you know of any meat, though, that tastes good with carrots? You could omit 'though' but you would lose the link to something said previously.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you. I think that my English is a bit elementary so I didn't catch the sense of the presence of `though`. Now it is a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Though" can mean "despite", "however". So we must ask "despite what?" What does "however" refer to?

The answer to that would be found in the previous sentences and the overall context.

It's likely those would explain the reason for "though". Look back at the rest of the discussion.

There's still a very small chance, the author wrote "though" [apropos of nothing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apropos_of_nothing#English).  In such a case, you're right it doesn't make sense.

Comment: thank you. I think the author could refer to something he has written before and not [apropos of nothing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/apropos_of_nothing#English).